# IIS 8.5 URL ReWrite

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

I have an asp.net application hosted on two servers.

Server 1 : http(s)://server1.domain.com

Server 2 : http://server2.domain.com

Now i have to write URL Rewrite rule so that all the "HTTP" requests coming to server1 should be redirected to server2 but all the "HTTPS" requests coming to server1 should be handled by server1 it self.

Thanks in advance for the help...

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following url rewrite rule:

```
<rule name="Redirect to HTTP" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="https://*.server1.domain.com/(*)" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://server2.domain.com/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Thanks for the Reply.. but the following code worked for me..

<rule name="Http_Redirect" patternSyntax="ECMAScript">
 <match url="(.*)" />
 <conditions>
  <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
 </conditions>
 <action type="Rewrite" url="http://server2.domain.com/{R:0}" />
</rule>