# Why is IIS 8.5 URL Rewrite throwing a 404 error?

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-8

We have modified our file structure a bit since we've found an issue with the result in my other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35464917/url-rewrite-troubleshoot/35484433?noredirect=1#comment58663397_35484433) and we now we're back where we've started. I have checked out this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31271012/iis-8-5-url-rewrite) but there is no answer to that question either.

We want the URL to show: https://devbox.mysite.com/kb/article/test-article-1 on the browser.

Below is my URL Rewrite:

```
<rule name="Article-rewrite" enabled="true">
    <match url=".com/kb/article/(.*)$" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://devbox.mysite.com/kb/article/?artID={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

I have enabled Failed Request Tracing to trace rewrite rules on the IIS but when I added the rules I do not see the Rewrite as an option even though this [instruction](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) showed that it's there. This is my settings and it's not showing option. Anyway, this is just a side issue to diagnose my url rewrite issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I finally figured out the answer to my question. The match URL will match the folder kb/artitcle/ and the a-ZA-Z- will only allow word and dash. In my situation, there will only be one parameter being passed so I intentionally ignoring the ampersand character because in CommonSpot CMS it adds a **&cs_pgIsInLView=1** to the end of the URL which causes the rewrite rule to break. So by ignoring this ampersand, it works in my situation. The query_string pattern 1 will ignore rewrite when I tried to login to the page with the url https://devbox.mysite.com/index.cfm?login=1. I'm guess there may be other better ways than this one but for now, this will have to do.

```
<rule name="Article-rewrite" enabled="true">
    <match url="^kb/article/([a-zA-Z\-]+)$" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="1" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="kb/article/?artID={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```